# What causes Error: Outlet is not activated when using an http service?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

My angular2 app uses an ngfor directive to display data from a json array. Previously I had hardcoded the json array into the component for testing purposes and the app worked perfectly. Now I have switched out the hardcoded json array for a service that uses an http request to supply the json array. I can click on the link that supplies this data a few times (varies between 2-4 times), and it works fine, and then it throws the error

This is app.routes.ts

```
...
{path:'deals', component:Deals},
...
```

The router link

```
<li id="deals" (click)="loadField('deals')"><a [routerLink]="['/deals']"><p class="propertyNavItem" id="dealsText">Deals</p></a></li>
```

The deals component

```
  dev_file:string = "dev_files/deals.json";
  list:Array<string>;

  constructor(private ghttp: GeneralHttpService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.ghttp.getRecommendations(this.dev_file).subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.list = data.items;
      },
      error => console.log(error),
      () => console.log("done")
    );
  }
```

The ghttp service

```
@Injectable()
export class GeneralHttpService{

  constructor(private http:Http){};

  getRecommendations(url:string){
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json() );
  }
}
```

The error thrown is this. It looks to be the same as the issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9479

> ```
> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Outlet is not activated browser_adapter.js:86
> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Outlet is not activated browser_adapter.js:77:13
>
> STACKTRACE: browser_adapter.js:77:13
>
> resolvePromise@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32
> makeResolver/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:515:14
> Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:20
> NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:45:32
> Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:20
> Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:25
> scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:53
> Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
> NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:36:32
> Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:355:24
> Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
> drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:26
> ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22
>  browser_adapter.js:77:13
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The http is an asynchronous operation. Your list variable is probably not yet populated when the template is rendered.

Try using the "elvis operator" (?) in your ngFor, something like this:

```
*ngFor="let listElement of list?"
```

Comment: Plus it seems like if it works once or twice, then it should work all of the time, the get request is to a local file not a server.

Comment: It seems that this is an open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9479